# Problem with installing dlib module for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, dlib

Excuse my ignorance. I'm new to using OpenCv and need to install the `dlib` module, but when I try it the following error appears

```
you have to use a version of Visual Studio that supports c ++ 11. Starting with
As of December 2017, the only version that has sufficient c ++ 11 compatibility
to compile the Python API dlib is a fully updated Visual Studio 2015 or a
Fully upgrade Visual Studio 2017. Previous versions of any of these completely
Visual Studio 2017 updated. The previous version of any of these compilers has
Poor c ++ 11 support and you will not be able to compile the python extension.
*** SO UPDATE YOUR VISUAL STUDY TO PERFORM THIS REMOTE ERROR ***
```

I use sublime text, but the error is due to something from Visual Studio, and I don't understand if it is mandatory to use Visual Studio for this module.

Despite the error, the module seems to be installed so it can import, but it seems to be incomplete because when viewing its content with `dir(dlib)`, only this appears

```
>>> import dlib
>>> dir (dlib)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I don't know if it is finally installed or if I need to resolve that error to be able to use it as I said I have no experience with this module.

Comment: did you compiled DLib from source? or just pip install?

Comment: i did porcess to install cmake and download dlib direct from of oficial page an execute setup with python setup.py install but throw this error

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a virtual env with python or conda?

Comment: No bro, i do not know what is conda   ... i need those conda for i can use dlib?

Comment: you don´t need Conda, I suggest creating a virtual environment in order to install all libraries that you need in your project